# C# Timer for Millisecond Waits

Tags: c#, timer

Every n*x milliseconds I perform an action where n = 0, 1, 2, ...; x is some increment.

Example - every 25 milliseconds I perform a calculation.

This action can take fewer than x seconds for each increment. As a result, I need a way **in C#** to wait the remaining (x - actual_time) milliseconds.

Example - if the calculation only takes 20 milliseconds, I need to wait 5 more milliseconds before re-running the calculation.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: How important is the exact timer precision?  It will be very difficult to get high resolution timing in a high-level language like C#, with garbage collection on an OS that has context switching.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe the reason why you think you need to perform an action with such high time resolution? Perhaps there is a better way to achieve what you need? Or maybe a way to handle the inaccuracy of timing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I need a way in C# to wait the remaining (x - actual_time) milliseconds.

I presume that is C# running on Windows.

And there is your problem. Windows is not a "realtime" operating system.

The best you can do if you need millisecond-grade timing precision is to set the thread priority of your thread extremely high, and then busy-wait while querying the high performance timer (Stopwatch).

**You cannot yield to another thread**; the other thread could run for as much as 16 milliseconds before the operating system context switches it, and of course unless you are the highest priority thread, you have no guarantee that control is coming back to you after those 16 milliseconds are up.

Now, setting thread priority high and then busy waiting is one of the most rude things you can possibly do; essentially you will be taking control of the user's machine and not allowing them to do anything else with it.

Therefore what I would do is *abandon this course of action entirely*. Either, (1) consider obtaining an operating system designed for realtime process control if that is in fact your application, rather than an operating system designed for multitasking a bunch of line-of-business applications.  Or (2) abandon your requirement that the action happen exactly every 25 milliseconds. Just perform the calculation once and yield the remainder of your quantum to another thread. When you get control back, see if more than 25 ms has passed since you yielded; if it has not, yield again. If it has, start over and perform the calculation.

Comment: Now you say that, but we created a 1 millisecond real-time (to within acceptable jitter tolerances) system on windows by breaking all the rules of what you're supposed to do in a device driver :)

Comment: @Massif: Windows Vista and newer make use of Driver Signature Enforcement, which adds an additional barrier to this approach.

Answer (score 4):

That level of accuracy will be very difficult to achieve in a non real-time operating system like Windows. Your best bet might be to look into the multimedia timers.

The other .NET timers won't have the kind of resolution your need.

Answer (score 1):

At 25ms, you may be the wrong side of the resolution of your available timers in .Net.

However - as a general solution I'd probably attempt this a different way to your "do calculation..wait until 25ms has passed" approach.

A better way may well be to use a [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), on a 25ms trigger, to *trigger* the calculation.

```
var timer = new Timer(25);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                     {
                         DoCalc();
                     };
timer.Start();
```

In the above example, a `DoCalc` method will be called every 25 ms (timer resolution issues notwithstanding). You would need to consider what to do if your calculation *overran* it's allotted time though. As it stands, the above code would allow a second calculation to start, even if the previous had not completed.

Comment: My experience with System.Timers on my machine is that the maximum resolution of it is around 15 ms (on Windows XP) and it will only trigger on multiples of that. So if you set it for 25 ms, you'll probably get roughly 30 ms intervals. Of course, this is likely to vary with hardware and OS. However, this is still more accurate than trying to calculate how much time is left after doing the calculation and trying to set the timer for the remaining time as the OP originally suggested.

Comment: @MattBurland - fair point - it would be worth testing on the target environment, but may well be far too close to the resolution to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difficult one, and your options are fairly limited, as Eric Lippert and Matt Burland indicate. Basically, you can either

- resort to using multimedia timers (google "multimedia timer component" or "winmm.dll"), which, although supporting time resolutions down to 0.500 ms, are no longer recommended as of Windows Vista, require Win32 interop and may bump up your CPU usage quite noticeably, or
- come up with an approximated time slicing algorithm that will use the standard timer (whose resolution is usually 15.625 ms on multicore desktops), dynamically varying the timer interval upon each tick based on the difference of desired and actual time elapsed since the last timer tick (you can measure this fairly accurately using high resolution CPU performance counters, e.g. the Stopwatch class).

The latter solution will statistically give you a 40Hz timer in your sample use case, but you'll have significant jitter due to the low resolution of the timer you are using.

This is the tradeoff, the call is yours to make.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a high-precision timer I wrote. I get roughly <1ms avg precision on 25ms interval. But if Windows is busy it may come in late. It's fairly lean on CPU utilization. Feel free to use. It uses Sleep(1) when the next tick is more than 15ms away and then SpinUntil (which yields as needed) to keep CPU usage at bay. Uses .NET4 features.

Link: [High Precision Timer](https://gist.github.com/4669495)

Comment: Where's the CircularBuffer defined?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's this one: http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com   I added that comment to the gist as well. FYI