# Performance issue in webbrowser c#

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, timer, webbrowser-control

I have an winform application that read some text from a website. and make a html of that and display on a webpage control .The html consist of a javascript function(Timer) which move these text 1 by 1 pixel.The interval of the timer is user defined (1 to 100 milisecond).webbrowser control scroll the text as excepted till the interval is 15 milisec. if i decrease the interval it the speed of the text keeps constant. BUT when i play the same in the InternetExplorer then there lots of changes in the speed 1 milisecond timer behaves like 15 milisecond timer. please help me to resolve this.

Comment: You've described expected behavior - timer resolution in Windows is generally 15ms. Please clarify what advice you are looking for.

Comment: are you sure it's a `Performance` Issue and not a coding issue.. perhaps you have a Disposing of Objects issue going on it's really hard to lend advice based on what have stated in my opinion without seeing relative code

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov thnx for reply and sorry for my delay reply."Timer resolution in Windows is generally 15ms" what does it mean?. is this In webbrowser control the minimum duration is 15 ms?

Comment: @DJKRAZE thnx for reply and sorry for my delay reply. which code u want to see c# or java script code? and disposing of of object in c# or java script?

Comment: All timers will have minimum duration of about 15ms irrespective of language (well there are ways to get more frequently firing timers, but you'd know about it as you'd have to write code to do so. See [1ms wait](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891879/c-sharp-timer-for-millisecond-waits) question for info). Since normally one uses speed in units per second it generally not a problem for regular UI updates.