# Task scheduler run task few milliseconds too early

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, taskscheduler

I have a task with a trigger:

```
At 0:00 every day - after triggered, repeat every 1 hours for a duration of 1 day.
```

And inside my application I read the time this way:

```
dateTimeUtcNow = DateTime.Now;
```

And sometimes, very rarely, dateTimeUtcNow shows the time a few milliseconds before full hour like `2015-11-11 14:59:59,914`

The server runs on Windows Server 2012 R2, I could accept this on home version but not production.

Why? Is this a bug? How can I prevent this?

Comment: Change the trigger for example to 0:01 instead of 0:00?

Comment: ok I can do it, but why does it happen ?

Comment: Here is a similar question on SU: [Why is Windows Task Scheduler starting my tasks early?](http://superuser.com/questions/396237/why-is-windows-task-scheduler-starting-my-tasks-early) If I had to guess I'd say it's an issue with the timer accuracy being limited.

Comment: @shurik That would make it run late when it works. Best to check that the current time is what you want and reschedule/sleep if need be.

Comment: 86 milliseconds is a lot sooner. Is the scheduled task and the receiving app on the same machine?

Comment: If the machine is on a NTP, that might have caused the issue

Comment: I believe it is because Windows operating system is **not** a [Real-time operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)

Comment: There's a similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891879/c-sharp-timer-for-millisecond-waits) that also has an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out Eric Lippert's article on the accuracy, or rather the lack of, of DateTime. [Link here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/08/precision-and-accuracy-of-datetime.aspx)

Key paragraph from the article:

> In short, the question “what time is it?” really should only be
>   answered to a level of precision that reflects the level of accuracy
>   inherent in the system. Most computer clocks are not accurately
>   synchronized to even within a millisecond of official time, and
>   therefore precision beyond that level of accuracy is a lie. It is
>   rather unfortunate, in my opinion, that the DateTime structure does
>   surface as much precision as it does, because it makes it seem like
>   operations on that structure ought to be accurate to that level too.
>   But they almost certainly are not that accurate.

If you really need the timer to go off before midnight and not sooner then you will have to force a "slightly" future date/time as has already been suggested in the comments. You do not really have any more control than this.